Horror movie help? Pretty low budget too
Hi I saw the trailer for this movie a year ago but it might be older. Basically 2 girls and 2 guys sneak into an aslyum after it is closed because one of the girls claims she a psychic and one of the guys doesn't believe her. The main girl isn't really sure she should come alone but she does anyways. They call upon the spirits and wound up having the guy who doesn't believe in this getting possessed. He gets all these powers and locks them in the hospital/asylum...what is this movie? 

This is the eye-wateringly bad Seance: The Summoning:

So I was pleased and even kind of charmed that the movie only really has four people, a group of college kids who go to a morgue in order to conduct a seance. Why? Well, that's kind of novel too - one of them claims to be a medium and another doesn't believe her. So off they go, with the skeptical one betting the "medium" that if she can't summon a spirit, she'll be deemed a fraud and then she has to come to his band's show.

Trailer here.

There are tons of similar abandoned asylum films, but this is possibly Boo from 2005. It's about 2 guys and 2 girls (though they're later joined by others) sneaking into an abandoned hospital on Halloween. The main girl is psychic and is able to converse with the ghosts, and one of the guys is later possessed and won't let them leave. Here's the trailer:



